# Improving R Code for Memory Experiment

Tags: r

I am working on a data set for my experiment  and I am trying to find out how how many trials resulted in an incorrect action on the part of the participant. In my table (see below) I added three columns at the end: prefix, corrfix, and errfix (0 indicates error and a numerical value indicates a correct action). What I want to start with is seeing how many trials per participant resulted in an incorrect action for the prefix column (i.e., there is no numerical value for that trial, indicating that they did no perform a correct action).

```
   RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL CURRENT_FIX_INDEX identifier prefix corrfix errfix
1                     1091                 1         86      0       0      0
2                     1091                 2         86      0       0      0
3                     1091                 3         86   1229       0      0
4                     1091                 4         86      0       0      0
5                     1091                 5         86      0       0      0
6                     1091                 1        110      0       0      0
7                     1091                 2        110    764       0      0
8                     1092                 3         22    202       0    202
9                     1092                 4         22    120       0      0
10                    1092                 5         22      0       0      0
11                    1092                 6         22      0       0      0
12                    1092                 7         22      0       0      0
13                    1092                 8         22      0       0      0
14                    1092                 9         22    510       0      0
15                    1092                10         22    330       0      0
16                    1092                11         22      0       0     57
```

I have been working on a code, but it will return multiple lines (of the same trial) when I only want trials where there is no numerical value (each participant should different trials per line) I would appreciate any help or suggestions. I am trying hard to refine my R skills.

```
  flag=0
  flag=1
  if(new[i,]$CURRENT_FIX_INDEX==1){
  flag=1
  }
  if (flag==1) {
  if(new[i,]$prefix==0){
  cbind(new$RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL, new$identifier)}
```

Comment: Which column represents participants?

Comment: I can't parse your code, but I think you can probably get rid of your loop and if statements by replacing them with a call to `ddply()` from plyr, `transform()` and `ifelse()`. If you can add your expected output, I imagine someone will provide some specific trips on addressing your problems.

Comment: RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL represents participants @TylerRinker

Comment: @chase I want an output that simply looks like this:

Comment: ID   identifier 
      1001 23
      1001 45
      1001 23
      1001 45
I want a running count of how many trials were lost due to participants not fixating correctly.

Comment: Jason your minimal example is a little bit to sparse to work with.  May I suggest you add to the data frame so you have at least 2 different RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL IDs so we can have a scenario more like you're dealing with.

Comment: It is a fairly large data set but I included a little more.

Comment: @Jason I adapted my response to address the new info you gave.  I make a suggestion at the end of my answer for further refinements if this isn't correct so that we can better understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure exactly what you're after.  It seems like you want to look at RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL and the identifier as grouping.  So in your data frame above we have 5 observations of 1091 and label and 86 identifier and then 2 observations of 1091 label and 110 identifier.  You want to sum for the 5 observations of 1091 and 86 and then again for 1091 and 110.  If the sum is not greater than 0 we flag and return this LABEL and identifier.  Is this correct or do you want to look at just all 1091 label as a whole and see if there's anything other than 0 values?

The code beloe looks at these three groups (is this correct?):

```
$`1092.22`
   RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL CURRENT_FIX_INDEX identifier prefix corrfix errfix
8                     1092                 3         22    202       0    202
9                     1092                 4         22    120       0      0
10                    1092                 5         22      0       0      0
11                    1092                 6         22      0       0      0
12                    1092                 7         22      0       0      0
13                    1092                 8         22      0       0      0
14                    1092                 9         22    510       0      0
15                    1092                10         22    330       0      0
16                    1092                11         22      0       0     57

$`1091.86`
  RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL CURRENT_FIX_INDEX identifier prefix corrfix errfix
1                    1091                 1         86      0       0      0
2                    1091                 2         86      0       0      0
3                    1091                 3         86   1229       0      0
4                    1091                 4         86      0       0      0
5                    1091                 5         86      0       0      0



$`1091.110`
  RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL CURRENT_FIX_INDEX identifier prefix corrfix errfix
6                    1091                 1        110      0       0      0
7                    1091                 2        110    764       0      0
```

The code:

```
error.count <- function(column){
    x <- rle(sort(column))
    ifelse(sum(x[[2]])==0, TRUE, FALSE)
}

outcome <- aggregate(prefix~RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL+identifier, dat, error.count)
outcome[outcome$prefix==1, ] #return just those Labels and identifiers with all zeros
```

In this case you'll get nothing returned because you don't have any data that fits these circumstances.  I might suggest further refining the data you provide that will generate the circumstances you're trying to identify.

Comment: What I want for now is just participants and the actual identifier (trial code). If the trial has all 0's and no numerical value I want returned the participant ID and the identifier code @TylerRinker

Comment: looking at the errors in the corrfix column might be easier. If there is no numerical value within the identifier grouping, it will be counted as error or zero. If this condition is met I want the subject and the identifier number printed, no sums. The problem I was having was that it would print every line with a zero, I am only concerned with the trial where it occurred. @TylerRinker

Comment: fixating on the prefix image was relatively easy, thus the reason why you had nothing returned.

Comment: @Jason try my code and see if it works.  I think it will if the identifiers are unique to the RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL.

Comment: If you want it to return the rows from the original data frame that meet this condition use `dat[dat$identifier%in%outcome$identifier, ]`

Comment: What is returned is something like this:

Comment: what I am looking for are identifier codes where there are all 0's, that is,  there will be no numerical values nested within the identifier variable. the output should have the subject and the identifer where there are 0's. So it would look like: 1097 97 then 1097 56 on the next line then 1097 45...

Comment: Can you clarify something for me? In the error.count function u say if sum==0, true, else false, but when  you call outcome  you put == 1. When this is done I get true statements returned, but is that stating the value is not equal to 0?

Comment: In the error.count function a 0 is a zero because that's what we're looking for.  In the outcome call I use `prefix==1` because I'm looking for when the cases are all zeros.  I assigned `TRUE` to cases of all zeros and the `prefix==1` actually means `prefix==TRUE` as R evaluates `TRUE` as 1 and `FALSE` as 0.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I think you gave me something to work with!